# Problems With Making Things Dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Everything Works Fine if I create a duplicate Manually, But when I try to duplicate elements using j-query the function doesn't work except on the original created entry.The first input tag has a auto-complete source linked with the class that also only works with the original elements and not with the clones.

```
<div class="row add">
      <form id="form1" action="#">
        <input class="col-md-offset-1 col-xs-3 inpro clac" id="inpro1">
        <input class="col-xs-1 mrp calc" id="mrp1">
        <input class="col-xs-1 qt calc" id="qt1">
        <input class="col-xs-1 dis calc" id="dis1">
        <div class="col-xs-2 amt calc" id="amt1"></div>
        <input type="submit" class="sub" id="sum1">
      </form>
    </div>
    <button class="row col-md-offset-1 col-xs-1 add" id="copy">Add</div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.calc').blur(function(e){
        var k = this.id.substr(this.id.length-1);
        var mrp =   parseFloat( $('#mrp'+k).val()   );
        var qt =    parseFloat( $('#qt'+k).val()    );
        var di =    $('#dis'+k).val();
        var dis =   parseFloat( di );
        var disc = di.substr(di.length-1);
        var amt = "";
        if (mrp>0 && qt>0 && dis>0) {
            if (disc === "%") {
                amt = mrp*qt - mrp*qt*dis/100;
            } else {
                amt = mrp*qt - dis;
            }
            var amount = "Rs."+ " " + Math.round( amt ) + " "+ "/-";
        }
        $('#amt'+k).html(amount);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    var scale = $("#copy").click(function() {
        var add = $(".add");
        var cnt = add.length + 1;
        add.eq(0).clone().insertBefore(this)
        .find("form").attr("id", "form" + cnt)
        .find("input, div").each(function() {
            this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+/, cnt);
            if ($(this).is('div')) {
                $(this).text = $(this).text("");
            } else {
                this.value = null;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UwMML/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize your calc function after the new elements have been added:

```
function calc() {
    $('.calc').blur(function (e) {
        var k = this.id.substr(this.id.length - 1);
        var mrp = parseFloat($('#mrp' + k).val());
        var qt = parseFloat($('#qt' + k).val());
        var di = $('#dis' + k).val();
        var dis = parseFloat(di);
        var disc = di.substr(di.length - 1);
        var amt = "";
        if (mrp > 0 && qt > 0 && dis > 0) {
            if (disc === "%") {
                amt = mrp * qt - mrp * qt * dis / 100;
            } else {
                amt = mrp * qt - dis;
            }
            var amount = "Rs." + " " + Math.round(amt) + " " + "/-";
        }
        $('#amt' + k).html(amount);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}

calc();

var scale = $("#copy").click(function () {
    var add = $(".add");
    var cnt = add.length + 1;
    add.eq(0).clone().insertBefore(this)
        .find("form").attr("id", "form" + cnt)
        .find("input, div").each(function () {
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+/, cnt);
        if ($(this).is('div')) {
            $(this).text = $(this).text("");
        } else {
            this.value = null;
        }
    });
    calc();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/UwMML/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UwMML/4/),

You have to have the binding function separate, because you will have to use that to bind blur event each time you add a set of input fields. In your code, blur event is bound to .calc only one time.

This part will do the first event binding

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    reBind();
});
```

For each time you click on Add button, this function will get executed. It will unbind all the prior bindings (to make the DOM overhead minimize) and re-bind blur event to all .calc inputs

```
function reBind(){
    $('.calc').unbind("blur").blur(function(e){
            var k = this.id.substr(this.id.length-1);
            var mrp =   parseFloat( $('#mrp'+k).val()   );
            var qt =    parseFloat( $('#qt'+k).val()    );
            var di =    $('#dis'+k).val();
            var dis =   parseFloat( di );
            var disc = di.substr(di.length-1);
            var amt = "";
            if (mrp>0 && qt>0 && dis>0) {
                if (disc === "%") {
                    amt = mrp*qt - mrp*qt*dis/100;
                } else {
                    amt = mrp*qt - dis;
                }
                var amount = "Rs."+ " " + Math.round( amt ) + " "+ "/-";
            }
            $('#amt'+k).html(amount);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
}
```